# What does the one function $\mathbf{1}_{i,y^{(t)}}$ exactly mean in backward propagation of RNN in the book "Deep learning" of Bengio

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

It confused me for a long time what is $\mathbf{1}_{i,y^{(t)}}$ exactly mean in (10.18) below.

It is in the Chapter 10 on RNN of the book [LeCun, Yann, Yoshua Bengio, and Geoffrey Hinton. "Deep learning." nature 521.7553 (2015): 436.](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html)

Because the ${i,y^{(t)}}$ doesn't seem to be a condition while the author has introduced a condition function as $\mathbf{1}_\text{condition} = 1$ if condition is true or $=0$ if the condition is false.

It is computing the gradient of the log-likelihood with backward propagation in recurrent neural network.

Instead of $\hat{y}_i^{(t)}− \mathbf{1}_{i,y^{(t)}}$, I found my solution might be 
$$
(\hat{y}^{(t)}_i-y_i^{(t)})\dfrac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})\sum_j\exp(z_j)-(\exp(z_i))^2}{(\sum_j\exp(z_j))^2}
$$
It is based on the prior assumption of Gaussian distribution with $\sigma=1$

Below is the equation I am asking about:

> The gradient $\nabla_{o^{(t)}}L$ on the outputs at time step $t$, for all $i$, $t$, is as
>   follows:
>   $$
> (\nabla_{o(t)}L)_i 
> = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
> = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial L^{(t)}}\dfrac{\partial L^{(t)}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
> = \hat{y}_i^{(t)}− \mathbf{1}_{i,y^{(t)}}.   \qquad\qquad (10.18)
> $$

While, the corresponding notes are:

> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \boldsymbol{a}^{(t)} &= \boldsymbol{b} +\boldsymbol{Wh}^{(t−1)} + \boldsymbol{Ux}^{(t)} &(10.8)\\
> \boldsymbol{h}^{(t)} &= \tanh(\boldsymbol{a}^{(t)}) &(10.9)\\
> \boldsymbol{o}^{(t)} &= \boldsymbol{c} + \boldsymbol{V h}^{(t)} &(10.10)\\
> \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)} &= \text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{o}^{(t)}) &(10.11)
> \end{align*}
> $$

And I wonder which version of softmax function is used here?
$$
\text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{z})=\dfrac{\exp(z_i)}{\sum_j\exp(z_j)}
$$
or
$$
\text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{z})=\dfrac{\exp(z_i-\max_kz_k)}{\sum_j\exp(z_j-\max_kz_k)}
$$
?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors or the publisher may have corrected the inconsistent notation. The current version online looks like below:
[image]

Here the $\mathbf{1}_{\text{condition}}$ is the indicator function, as you mentioned.

Regarding the two version of `softmax`, use the first one for calculating gradient. The second version is for improving numerical stability, and mathmatically it should yield the exact same value as the first version.

Comment: Thank  you for your help! I have a further question that shouldn't $y^{(t)}$ be a vector $\boldsymbol{y}^{t}$ with the same length as $\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}$? Then how could it be equal to a scalar $i$?

Comment: And the expression of $L$? 
I have thought it was based on assumption that :$p(y|x;\theta)\sim \mathcal{N}(y,\mu=\hat{y},\sigma=1)$, i.e Gaussian distribution. 
So $L=\sum_t\frac{1}{2}\Vert\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}-\boldsymbol{y}^{(t)}\Vert^2+Constant$

But it seems that here the authors use the cross entropy loss like $L=\sum_t \boldsymbol{y}^{(t)}t\log{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}}$?

So do you know what is the expression of  loss $L$ here?Thank you!

Comment: $L$ is the cross-entropy loss defined in (10.14). For the indicator function, you are right that the condition is "scalar $i$"=="vector $y^{t}$", in this case the indicator function returns a vector whose k'th elements are indicator of whether that element in $i$ equals the k'th element of $y^{t}$.  Similar like you compare a 1-D numpy array with a scalar in python.

Comment: Thank you for help! I was too impatient to ask the question when I hadn't read the chapters before RNN because I had thought it simple.  I read the underlying chapter again and wrote an answer below to prove the equation (10.18).  By the way, I think $y^{(t)}$ here is a scalar at certain time t.

Comment: you are right. I think the author means $t^{(t)}$ to be a scalar. I was thinking it as a one hot encoding, but it's not here.

Comment: yes, in the simple example it is a scalar, then it is generalized to vector version.

Answer (score 2):

I am too impatient to ask the question when I haven't read the chapters before RNN because I have thought it simple. 
Soon I found it more complicated than I had thought.

Then I read the underlying chapter again and I think I can answer my own question now.

The expression of (10.18) is as the answer by @user12075:

> the authors have corrected the notion $\mathbf{1}_{i,y^{(t)}}$ to $\mathbf{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}$.

Then I want to prove the new version of (10.18).

If there is something I have misunderstood, please tell me! Thank you!

First, I'll explain the loss function and underlying concepts：

According to  (10.14):
\begin{equation}
L=\sum_tL^{(t)}=-\sum_t\log p_{model}(y^{(t)}|\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(t)}\})  \label{loss}
\end{equation}

at each time step t, label $y^{(t)}$ is a scalar, for example, it is a multiclass classification with n classes, then $y^{(t)}\in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$

However at each time step t, output of the model $\hat{\boldsymbol {y}}^{(t)}$ is a vector with length n, instead of a scalar approximate to the scalar $y^{(t)}$,it is represented as the probabilities of $y^{(t)}$ taking different values.

That is

\begin{align}
\hat{\boldsymbol {y}}^{(t)}=&
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{model}(y^{(t)}=1|\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(t)}\})\\
p_{model}(y^{(t)}=2|\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(t)}\})\\
\vdots\\
p_{model}(y^{(t)}=n|\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(t)}\})
\end{bmatrix}\\
\text{for short is:}&
\begin{bmatrix}
p(y^{(t)}=1|X;\Theta)\\
p(y^{(t)}=2|X;\Theta)\\
\vdots\\
p(y^{(t)}=n|X;\Theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

And in the training, value of $y^{(t)}$ at each t is already known.

So in (10.14), we assume $ t=3,n=10 $, $ y^{(1)}=3,y^{(2)}=5,y^{(3)}=4 $

then
\begin{align}
L&=-\log p(y^{(1)}=3|X)-\log p(y^{(2)}=5|X)-\log p(y^{(3)}=4|X)\\
&=-\log \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(1)}_3 -\log \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(2)}_5 -\log \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(3)}_4
\end{align}

While the subscript of $\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}$ denotes the index of element of the vector

So the general expression is:

\begin{align}
L&=-\sum_t \log p_{model}(y^{(t)}|X)\\
&=-\sum_t \log\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}\label{grad_L_o} \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{align}

Now we can begin to verify the equation (10.18) on the book:

\begin{align}
(\nabla_{o(t)}L)_i 
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\\
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial L^{(t)}}\frac{\partial L^{(t)}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\\
&= \hat{y}_i^{(t)} - \mathbf{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}.   \qquad\qquad (10.18)
\end{align}

Note:
$i=1,2,\cdots,n,\quad y^{(t)}\in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$

And 
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{a}^{(t)} &= \boldsymbol{b} +\boldsymbol{Wh}^{(t−1)} + \boldsymbol{Ux}^{(t)} &(10.8)\\
\boldsymbol{h}^{(t)} &= \tanh(\boldsymbol{a}^{(t)}) &(10.9)\\
\boldsymbol{o}^{(t)} &= \boldsymbol{c} + \boldsymbol{V h}^{(t)} &(10.10)\\
\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)} &= \text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{o}^{(t)}) &(10.11)
\end{align}
While 
\begin{equation}
 (\text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{x}))_i := \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_j \exp(x_j)}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}_i^{(t)} = \frac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})}{\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})}
\end{equation}

by(1), we begin to compute the following equation:
\begin{align}
(\nabla_{o(t)}L)_i 
=- \frac{\partial \log\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\label{grad_L_o_i} \qquad\qquad (2)
\end{align}

We compute each item in the sum respectively:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \log\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
=\frac{1}{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}\cdot 
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
\end{align}

Here are two cases to be considered for $\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}$:

$i=y^{(t)}$ vs $i\ne y^{(t)}$

When $i=y^{(t)}$:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
&=\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\\
&=\frac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})\cdot\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})-\exp(o_i^{(t)})\cdot\exp(o_i^{(t)})}{(\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)}))^2}\\
&=\frac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})}{\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})} - (\frac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})}{\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})})^2\\
&=\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i - (\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i)^2
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \log\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
&=\frac{1}{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}\cdot 
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\\
& = \frac{1}{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}\cdot (\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i - (\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i)^2)\\
&=1 - \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i
\end{align}

When $i\ne y^{(t)}$:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
&=\frac{-\exp(o_i^{(t)})\cdot\exp(o_{y^{(t)}}^{(t)})}
{(\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)}))^2}\\
&=- \frac{\exp(o_i^{(t)})}{\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})}\cdot \frac{\exp(o_{y^{(t)}}^{(t)})}{\sum_j \exp(o_j^{(t)})}\\
&= - \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \log\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}
&=\frac{1}{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}\cdot 
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}{\partial o_i^{(t)}}\\
& = \frac{1}{\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i}\cdot (- \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_{y^{(t)}})\\
&=- \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i
\end{align}

So substitute into (2), we got :
\begin{align}
(\nabla_{o(t)}L)_i 
&=
\begin{cases}
\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i-1 &\text{If } i=y^{(t)},\\
\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}^{(t)}_i &\text{If } i\ne y^{(t)}
\end{cases}\\
&=\hat{y}_i^{(t)} - \mathbf{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}.   \qquad\qquad \text{which is (10.18)}
\end{align}

So (10.18) proved.